# strange behaviour of copy constructor between function parameter and temporary variable

Tags: c++

I have example like:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Point {
private:
    int x;
    int y;

public:
    Point(int i, int j) : x{ i }, y{ j } {
        cout << "CTOR POINT: {x=" << x << ", y=" << y << ", addr=" << this << "}" << endl;
    }

    Point(const Point& p) {
        cout << "COPY CTOR from POINT: {x=" << p.x << ", y=" << p.y << ", addr=" << &p << "} to POINT: {x=" << x << ", y=" << y << ", addr=" << this << "}" << endl;
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
    }

    Point& operator=(const Point& p) {
        cout << "OP= from POINT: {x=" << p.x << ", y=" << p.y << ", addr=" << &p << "} to POINT: {x=" << x << ", y=" << y << ", addr=" << this << "}" << endl;
        x = p.x;
        y = p.y;
        return *this;
    }

    ~Point() {
        cout << "DTOR POINT: {x=" << x << ", y=" << y << ", addr=" << this << "}" << endl;
    }
};

Point func1(Point p) {
    cout << "entered in func1 function" << endl;
    cout << "exiting in func1 function" << endl;
    return p;               // p will be copied to temporary variable with Point(const Point&) ctor.
                            // p will be dtored.
}

int main() {
    cout << "entered in main function" << endl;
    Point p1{ 5, 10 };      // initialized p1 with Point(int, int) ctor.
    p1 = func1(p1);         // in call to func1(), p1 arg will be copied to parameter p with Point(const Point&) ctor.
                            // on return, temporary variable will be assigned to p1 using operator=(const Point&) func.
                            // temporary variable will be dtored.
    Point p2{ 500, 1000 };  // initialized p2 with Point(int, int) ctor.
    p1 = p2;                // p2 will be assigned to p1 using operator=(const Point&) func.
    cout << "exiting in main function" << endl;
                            // p2 will be dtored.
                            // p1 will be dtored.
}
```

And the output is:

```
entered in main function
CTOR POINT: {x=5, y=10, addr=003EFE38}
COPY CTOR from POINT: {x=5, y=10, addr=003EFE38} to POINT: {x=5, y=10, addr=003EFD28}
entered in func1 function
exiting in func1 function
COPY CTOR from POINT: {x=5, y=10, addr=003EFD28} to POINT: {x=-858993460, y=-858993460, addr=003EFD4C}
DTOR POINT: {x=5, y=10, addr=003EFD28}
OP= from POINT: {x=5, y=10, addr=003EFD4C} to POINT: {x=5, y=10, addr=003EFE38}
DTOR POINT: {x=5, y=10, addr=003EFD4C}
CTOR POINT: {x=500, y=1000, addr=003EFE28}
OP= from POINT: {x=500, y=1000, addr=003EFE28} to POINT: {x=5, y=10, addr=003EFE38}
exiting in main function
DTOR POINT: {x=500, y=1000, addr=003EFE28}
DTOR POINT: {x=500, y=1000, addr=003EFE38}
```

As we can see, parameter `p` and `temporary variable` are constructed with copy constructors. Members of Point are build-in types, so, they cannot be initialized by default if initializer list not specified in constructors.

Question:

Why parameter `p` has valid `x` and `y` as `5` and `10` before it gets to `cout` in `Point(const Point&)` constructor, while `temporary variable` has junk values?

Comment: if you downvote, please mention reason. I have doubt and asked question. If question doesnt meet SO rules, I will update or delete.

Comment: Currently, you have UB, as you read data member `x`,`y` in copy constructor before initializing them.

Comment: You read memory without first initializing it with a value. The compiler is free to push any kind of crap value at you - including an optimization, where the statically known main function initialization starts with pre-initialized values.

Comment: @Jarod42 be careful not to mix indeterminate values and undefined behavior. First would be *you can expect to read any kind of crap, but reading the crap is defined to do whatever the crap value would do anyway if you explicitely assign it* while UB would be the end of the universe as we know it.

Comment: Ok, so its UB. But getting consistent 5 and 10 values in parameter p led me to doubt. I see now, it may be optimization that compiler knows p1 object at compile time, so, it copied same value as parameter p..

Answer (score 0):

Your copy constructor is not properly implemented. Every constructor (including copy constructor) can have member initialization list. If provided, they will be executed in the order the data member were declared in the class. If not provided, the data members will be default initialized.

Just keep in mind that initialization of data members always occurs before the constructor body runs.

In your copy constructor, you failed to initialize your data members in a constructor initialization list. But you later read them which invoked UB. You may want to do:

```
Point(const Point& p) : x{ p.x }, y{ p.y } {
    std::cout << "COPY CTOR from POINT: {x=" << p.x << ", y=" << p.y
              << ", addr=" << &p << "} to POINT: {x=" << x 
              << ", y=" << y << ", addr=" << this << "}" << endl;
}
```

With the above, you shouldn't have UB.

[**Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/75f1c0cf2d98fabd)

Comment: Yes, I did that deliberately, and as I read if initialization list not specified, built-types will not be initialized, and thats what I get in temporary variable. But how parameter p is initialized to 5 and 10.

Comment: @UDPLover, I am not sure I understand your comment. What's your question?

Comment: @WhiZRiM I purposefully not written initializer list in copy constructor to get UB, and that I got in temporary variable. But not in parameter p, so, my question was why not UB in parameter p too... Parameter p I am talking is of function "func1"